# Minimum $Yp$ degree needed to solve to a nonhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

The khan Academy video "undetermined coefficients 1", shows khan solving:

$$y'' -3y' - 4y = 3e^{2x}$$

$$y_h = C_1e^{4x} + C_2e^{-x}$$

For $Y_p$ he starts with $Ae^{2x}$ and solves.

My textbook has the equation:

$$y'' - 6y' + 9y = e^{3t}$$

$$Y_h = C_1 e^{3t} + C_2te^{3t}$$

For $Y_p$ it starts with $At^2e^{3t}$.

I'm confused as why Khan was able to use a  $n$ degree polynomial (with $n$ being the max degree in $Y_h$) and the textbook needed an $n+1$ degree? Could you solve khan's equation with an $n+1$ degree ($Ate^{2x}$)?

Edit: changed plus to minus to show real roots

Comment: Are you sure of the first differential equation? I believe it should be $y'' -3y' -4y$. Otherwise, it has no real roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first case, there are no repeated roots where as for the second there are! It is sort of a general trick to give a candidate function for your particular solution these types, I am pretty sure these are in any  ODE textbook!

Comment: I found an equation today in the same book with the differential: y'' -2y' -8y + 3 = e^4t. The book starts Yp with Ate^4t . I don't understand where this comes from as it seems to be in the same form as Khan's equation, just with an added constant.

Comment: Ahhh! This is because $e^{4t}$ is a solution of the homogeneous equaton, so if you take the t out and just write down $Ae^{4t}$, the solution will satisfy $y''-2y'-8y=0$ which is clearly not what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Khan's differential equation, which is probably $y'' -3y' -4y$ has the characteristic equation $$r^2 -3r-4 = (r-1)(r+4).$$ Notice it has two distinct roots. Your book's equation has characteristic equation $$r^2-6r+9=(r-3)^2.$$ It has a double root, and therefore the exponentials won't be linearly independent. Since you have a second order linear differential equation, you need to look for solutions of the type $(At^2+Bt+C)e^{3t}$.

You could apply this method to Khan's example. You would need to try particular solutions $$y_{p_1} = (A_1 t^2 +B_1 t + C_1)e^{4t}$$ and $$y_{p_2} = (A_2 t^2 + B_2 t +C_2) e^{-t}.$$ You should find $A_1 = B_1 = A_2 = B_2 = 0$.

Comment: I thought the double root was taken care of In Y2 = **t**e^3t. If this is not the case than, what does multiplying by t do?

Comment: @knowads That does take care of the double root, **for the homogeneous solution**. For the particular solution you need to exclude that possibility by using a full second degree polynomial.

Comment: I found an equation today in the same book with the differential: **y'' -2y' -8y + 3 = e^4t**. The book starts Yp with **Ate^4t** . I don't understand where this comes from as it seems to be in the same form as Khan's equation, just with an added constant. @Mark Fantini

Comment: @knowads Mind if I ask what is your textbook?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the name. These are from a book my GSI pulls examples from and not from my actual HW textbook which is Fundamentals of Differential Equations 8th Edition Snider @Mark Fantini